# Handling ObjectDisposedExceptions on disconnected WCF channels

Tags: wcf, objectdisposedexception

When a method is called on a WCF channel that has been disconnected for some reason, it raises an ObjectDisposedException.

Now is normal operation this should not happen, but if for some reason it did, I would like to be able to handle the exception nicely by showing an error to the user like "An operation failed because the service is not connected".

The problem is I just get a generic disposed exception in my appwide exception handler, so I have no way of determining whether WCF threw it.

to get around this I currently have a wrapper class that simply wraps all service method calls with try/catch and rethrows any ObjectDisposedException's as a custom comms exception that my global handler can deal with. this is a load of boilerplate stuff I could do without though.

Is there any way of determining whether WCF threw the exception?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to encounter such problem, it seems it's difficult to determine whether the WCF throws exception. You can't use the CommunicationObject.Status for this problem, only when you try to use that channel, it throws exception to tell you that the channel is faulted.

Therefore, I used the way like yours.